# Opening local files from chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to open a local file on the filesystem/network drive (`c:\abc.xlsx` or `p:\abc.xlsx`)?

If so, is it possible to do it through a custom extension that I create for Google Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by setting the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

Instead of opening Chrome normally, run:

```
path\to\your\chrome\installation\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

[Source.](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/)

Comment: Not without a lot more work. You would have to write a backend which takes the new data from some web page you made and writes it back to a file.

Comment: This no longer works when using Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 finally provides a standard way to interact with local files, via the File API specification.

The spec provides several interfaces for accessing files from a 'local' filesystem:

1. File - an individual file; provides readonly information such as name, file size, mimetype, and a  reference to the file handle.
2. FileList - an array-like sequence of File objects. (Think  or dragging a directory of files from the desktop).
3. Blob - Allows for slicing a file into byte ranges.

When used in conjunction with the above data structures, the FileReader interface can be used to asynchronously read a file through familiar JavaScript event handling. Thus, it is possible to monitor the progress of a read, catch errors, and determine when a load is complete. In many ways the APIs resemble XMLHttpRequest's event model.

The first thing to do is check that your browser fully supports the File API:

```
// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.  
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Next, handle file selection:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                '</li>');
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

To read file, extend handleFileSelect as such:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Lastly, here is the file spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/